# How to resolve the rsAccessDenied from SQL Server Reporting Service

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I installed and configured the SQL Server Reporting Service 2022 on a Windows Server 2022. However, upon accessing the report server portal (native mode configured) the same admin account used to install the Reporting Service is denied access to the Report Server configurations page where I can add users and set permissions accordingly, i.e. https://reportserver/ReportServer. The following error is displayed on the web page, running Edge as an administrator and without administrator, also on IE. Error

> The permissions granted to user 'Domain\UserName' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied) Get Online Help

Please advise what could be the issue. The account is also a sysadmin on SQL, and it has RSExcute for both ReportServer and ReportServerTemp.

Comment: Run (your browser) as a local administrator on the localhost.

Comment: @ThomA The local administrator? please explain.

Comment: Right Click -> Run as Administrator...

Comment: @ThomA that is what I have been doing, the account I'm currently logged in an Admin account from a domain. i.e. Domain\UserAccountName.

Comment: The local administrator will always have access to the portal when run locally, @Andile . Rather than "reportserver", you could try "Localhost" for the server name, but it shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: @ThomA http://localhost/ReportServer still return rsAccessDenied.

Comment: Sounds like you *aren't* running as the local admin then.

Comment: My account that I am using is from AD, i.e Domain\UserAccount, the account is then added to the Administrators group in the server where Report Server is Installed and configured.

Comment: Is the actual local Administrator account, the one with the `S-1-5-32-500` SID, still enabled on your machine? Are you able to login to the SSRS report manager using that account?

Comment: [Under User Action, this page says "The administrator must also create one or more roles that define the tasks the user can perform and a scope. "](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/troubleshooting/rsaccesseddenied-reporting-services-error?view=sql-server-ver16#user-action)

Comment: @ourmandave the issue here is I cannot even access the Report Server portal after the installation has completed. I have configured the WebService, SQL Server and WebPortal, and when I navigate to https://servername/reportserver I get a "The permissions granted to user 'Domain\UserAccount' are insufficient for performing this operation. (rsAccessDenied)". This domain account is a member of the servers Administrators group.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It's a domain account and is a member of the Administrators group in the server running the report server. I only have SID ending with 545 and 544. And I presume for security purposes that account with SID 500 is disabled.

Comment: I understand that you're trying to use a domain account. At least for initial configuration, though, you need to be using a local administrator account.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning S-1-5-32-544 BuiltIn\Administrators: A built-in group. After the initial installation of the operating system, the only member of the group is the Administrator account. When a computer joins a domain, the Domain Admins group is added to the Administrators group. So, since the report server has only this the Built-in\Administrators group added by default, I should be able access the RSPortal, but in this case it's not happening. The S-1-5-domain-500 is disabled at the moment on that server.

Comment: Seems you have a chicken and egg problem, then. SSRS manages its own ACLs internally through the `dbo.Users` (in which it stores binary SIDs), `dbo.Roles` and `dbo.PolicyUserRole` tables. It won't care about your domain users or domain groups until you've logged in with an actual local administrator to grant them permissions.